Damaged contact on LED strip
I have a Meross LED light strip system. I wanted to extend it so I can run wires behind the wall to segments of the strips on shelves. Ok in theory, but my soldering skills are not great. I think the wires I had were too big and I was struggling to make a good connection. I think I have ruined the copper connector on the end attached to the power supply. The flux no longer flows onto the Red connector. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

The soldering iron could have been too hot, make sure you use flux.

The pad on the RED connector is gone. Maybe you can scratch the white solder resist to find the copper track below, corresponding to the RED input.
